# Is there a way to get custom reference in firebase RTD for android(java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseDatabase db =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference node = db.getReference("plantation");

.....

reference.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(obj);
```

as you can see the reference id starts from the value of "maxid" which is int, is there a way if can have id's like : DL00001

Comment: The keys are always Strings. Would you like to sequential node keys?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are free to use any string as a key, but as @AlexMamo states, they are always strings. If you want them to look something sequential like DL0001, DL0002 etc you could read them in as a string, cast the numeric part to an int, increment and then write them back out as a string; DL00002. HOWEVER, this is probably a bad idea. You are generally way better off letting Firebase create it's own node keys and then use a child node for ordering, if that's what you're after. We would really need more info as to *why* you want to do this to provide any concrete answer though.

Comment: For more on why this is an antipattern in Firebase: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [How to create auto incremented key in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519021/how-to-create-auto-incremented-key-in-firebase)